# ListView's list to connect in another activity using intent

Tags: android, listview, android-intent, android-activity

I'm really having trouble on using ClickListener(whether `OnClickListener` or `OnItemClickListener`) for my list in connecting to another activity. I have tried inserting some code for click events in my list, but it doesn't work. It always give me errors.
Below is the code for my *Alphabet Activity*

```
public class Alphabet_Activity extends Activity

{

private List<Alpha> myAlpha=new ArrayList<Alpha>();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_alphabet);

    populateAlphaList();
    populateListView();
    registerClickableList();
}
//------------------------------------------------------------>
//----->for contents of my list in ListView<------------------
//------------------------------------------------------------>
    private void populateAlphaList() 
{
    myAlpha.add(new Alpha("A", R.drawable.a));
    myAlpha.add(new Alpha("B", R.drawable.b));
    myAlpha.add(new Alpha("C", R.drawable.c));
    myAlpha.add(new Alpha("D", R.drawable.d));
    myAlpha.add(new Alpha("E", R.drawable.e));
    myAlpha.add(new Alpha("F", R.drawable.f));
    myAlpha.add(new Alpha("G", R.drawable.g));
    myAlpha.add(new Alpha("H", R.drawable.h));
    myAlpha.add(new Alpha("I", R.drawable.i));
    myAlpha.add(new Alpha("J", R.drawable.j));
    myAlpha.add(new Alpha("K", R.drawable.k));
    myAlpha.add(new Alpha("L", R.drawable.l));
    myAlpha.add(new Alpha("M", R.drawable.m));
    myAlpha.add(new Alpha("N", R.drawable.n));
    myAlpha.add(new Alpha("O", R.drawable.o));
    myAlpha.add(new Alpha("P", R.drawable.p));
    myAlpha.add(new Alpha("Q", R.drawable.q));
    myAlpha.add(new Alpha("R", R.drawable.r));
    myAlpha.add(new Alpha("S", R.drawable.s));
    myAlpha.add(new Alpha("T", R.drawable.t));
    myAlpha.add(new Alpha("U", R.drawable.u));
    myAlpha.add(new Alpha("V", R.drawable.v));
    myAlpha.add(new Alpha("W", R.drawable.w));
    myAlpha.add(new Alpha("X", R.drawable.x));
    myAlpha.add(new Alpha("Y", R.drawable.y));
    myAlpha.add(new Alpha("Z", R.drawable.z));
}
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
//----->for calling the values in Alpha Activity to Alphabet Activity<------------------
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
private void populateListView()
{
    ArrayAdapter<Alpha> adapter=new MyListAdapter();
    ListView list=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.alphaListView);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);           
}   
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------->
//----->for getting message after clicking one of the list<------------------
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------->
private void registerClickableList() {
    ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.alphaListView);
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View viewClicked,
                int position, long id) {

            Alpha clickedAlpha = myAlpha.get(position);
            String message = "You clicked " + position + clickedAlpha.getName();
            Toast.makeText(Alphabet_Activity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------>
//------>calling of values in Alpha Activity and contents in myAlpha<-----------
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------>
private class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Alpha>
{
    public MyListAdapter()
    {
        super(Alphabet_Activity.this, R.layout.alpha, myAlpha);

    }

    @Override
    public View getView( int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View itemView=convertView;
        if(itemView==null)
        {
            itemView=getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.alpha, parent,false);
        }

        //---------------------
        Alpha currentAlpha=myAlpha.get(position);

        ImageView imageView=(ImageView)itemView. findViewById(R.id.icon_Alpha);
        imageView.setImageResource(currentAlpha.geticonAlpha());


        TextView name=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.alpha_Name);
        name.setText(currentAlpha.getName());

        return itemView;
        //return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);


    }

}
 }
```

*Here is the code for my Alpha Activity*

```
public class Alpha {

private String Name;
private int iconAlpha;

public Alpha(String make, int iconAlpha) {
    super();
    this.Name = Name;
    this.iconAlpha = iconAlpha;
}
public String getName() {
    return Name;
}
public int geticonAlpha() {
    return iconAlpha;
}
}
```

Comment: Can you add the error you're getting?

Comment: You are calling this line twice
ListView list=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.alphaListView); you might want to look into it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is working fine. It just have a small mistake.

In Alpha class rename String make to Name.

For calling different activities add below code in your onItemClick

```
switch (position) {
            case 0: 
                Intent a = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AActivity.class);
                startActivity(a);
                break;

            case 1: 
                Intent b = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), BActivity.class);
                startActivity(b);
                break;
}
```

Similarly add cases as per your requirement.

or

You can create a array of string of all new activities in sequential order.

then you can get the activity name by arr[position]
and call

Intent b = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), arr[pos]);
                    startActivity(b);

Then in this case no switch case is required

Comment: public Alpha(String make, int iconAlpha) {
    super();
    this.Name = Name;--->Supposedly Name should be make... Thanks for reminding me... @sanky jain

Answer (score 0):

Remove

```
ListView list=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.alphaListView);
```

from populateListView() and registerClickableList().........................

Add it in onCreate method and then use the same object in both these functions.

Here you are creating two different objects.You need a single object

Comment: **Codes I posted on the top of the page is working and errors are already removed. What I wanted to happen is that once I clicked on a list in my ListView, it will direct me to another activity. I have tried putting an intent and OnItemClickListener just to connect to another activity. Say for example _Alphabet_Activity(my list and listview) contains a-z alphabet and once I select a in the list, it will direct me to a_activity(blank as for now only)_ ** **I'm just a newbie,PLEASE elaborate code and explanation-Thanks** @Sanky Jain

Comment: **_Alpha_Activity_ hold texts(a-z[Large Text]) with images(sign language[ImageViewer]) which I named as _String name_ and _int iconAlpha_ for my listview to contain while in the list.
_Alphabet_Activity_ holds my Listview which calls the variables in the Alpha_Activity.
How am I able to call different activities from a-z once item(a-z) in the list is clicked?  PLEASE help!
Need an additional code...**

Comment: i added a new answer, check it

Comment: I haven't need to remove these codes and it just works fine...@Piyush Gupta @sanky jain